# How to get IMEI number in C# xamarin forms android?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm working with C# xamarin forms android and I'm trying to get the IMEI number. I've been searching about it and everything I found doesn't works. Now I'm trying with this code but again, Doesn't works.

Errors:

1. The name **settings** does not exist in the current context.
2. The name **Forms** does not exist in the current context.

C# code:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(UniqueIdAndroid))]
namespace AppMobile.Models
{
    public class UniqueIdAndroid
    {
        public string GetIdentifier()
        {
            return Settings.Secure.GetString(Forms.Context.ContentResolver, Settings.Secure.AndroidId);
        }
    }
}
```

Somebody knows how could I resolve this or knows other solution? Thank you very much!

**UPDATE 1**

c# code:

```
using Android.OS;
using AppMobile.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using static Android.Provider.Settings;
using Android.Provider;
using Xamarin.Forms;

    [assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(UniqueIdAndroid))]
    namespace AppMobile.Models
    {
        public class UniqueIdAndroid : IDevice
        {
            public string GetIdentifier()
            {
                return Settings.Secure.GetString(Forms.Context.ContentResolver, Settings.Secure.AndroidId);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have added the IDevice interface that I don't know really what it should be and I fixed the settings problem with `using Android.Provider;`.
[this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0cbaad45-a3a1-435c-bbe8-8522344cd4aa/get-the-imei-number-of-the-device?forum=xamarinforms) shows that I have to call with this:

```
string deviceIdentifier = DependencyService.Get<IDevice>().GetIdentifier();
```

But i don't understand how to implement `IDevice` interface.

Someone can help me? Thank you very much!

**UPDATE 2**

so, now I can use the function.

C# code:

```
    using Android.OS;
using AppMobile.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using static Android.Provider.Settings;
using Android.Provider;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Android.Content;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(UniqueIdAndroid))]
namespace AppMobile.Models
{
    public class UniqueIdAndroid
    {
        
        public string GetIdentifier()
        {
            //return Settings.Secure.GetString(Forms.Context.ContentResolver, Settings.Secure.AndroidId);
            
            return Settings.Secure.GetString(Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver, Settings.Secure.AndroidId);
        }
        
    }
}
```

My problem is that this doesn't give me the IMEI. Insted it gives me the ID of the phone, ¿is there some way to get the IMEI string? Thank you very much!

Comment: Where are you getting this code from?  `Settings` is in the `Android.Provider` namespace.

Comment: Thank you @Jason ! I have resolved the settings problem with that. I posted in UPDATE 1 what I learnt but I can't resolve the Forms problem and the IDevice interface. Do you have any idea?

Comment: you either need to pass in the context as a parameter, or use Android code to get the current context

Comment: Thank you again @Jason ! Now it works. Do you know how could I retrieve the IMEI string intead of the ID? that's what I need and I can't achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr; 

mTelephonyMgr = (Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.TelephonyService);

string imei = mTelephonyMgr.GetMeid(0);
```

And from android document  [getMeid](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getMeid(int)), we know that  :

> Starting with API level 29, persistent device identifiers are guarded
> behind additional restrictions, and apps are recommended to use
> resettable identifiers (see Best practices for unique identifiers).
> This method can be invoked if one of the following requirements is
> met:
>
> - If the calling app has been granted the READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE    permission; this is a privileged permission that can only be granted
>   to apps preloaded on the device.
> - If the calling app is the device owner of a fully-managed device, a    profile owner of an organization-owned device, or their delegates
>   (see DevicePolicyManager.getEnrollmentSpecificId()).
> - If the calling app has carrier privileges (see    hasCarrierPrivileges()) on any active subscription.
> - If the calling app is the default SMS role holder

**Note:**

In general, you can't get `READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE` permission. It's only available to privileged system apps. Unless this is a personal app and you have a rooted device so you can make your app a privileged system app.

For more information, you can check document [getMeid](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getMeid(int)).